# Error when closing an already open Excel file

Tags: python, excel

I have a code to work with an already open Excel file (it actually just closes it so the rest of the code can work, and then opens it again at the end). It works in one of my computers, but not in the other - I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
file "executavel.py", line 48, in GetSquareRoot
File "site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 527, in __getattr__
AttributeError: Excel.Application.Workbooks
```

Here is the part of the code that raises the error (line 48 is "wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path)"):

```
xlApp = client.GetObject(None, "Excel.Application")
wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open('planilha.xlsx')
wb.Save()
wb.Close()
```

All Excel windows are closed except for the spreadsheet in question (there are no open pop-ups or anything). Is there a way to make this code work in both computers, or another way to close an already open Excel workbook?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to do but i would say if have to handle excel files try pandas.
Also provide better information about what you're tring to do

Comment: I'm trying to close an Excel file that is open when running the code; pandas doesn't work because it needs the file to be already closed. My code works in the computer I used to write it, but not on others